# SQL - Summary of transactions - Calculate start end time of transactions based on column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL table which holds transactions of products and cumulative total of packed products each minute from a machine.

I'm trying to summarize this table (in a sql query) into product runs.

[image: Example Table]

[image: Example Output - Summary]

- The start times are denoted by the first record of the product where cumulative is > 0
- The finish times are denoted by the last record of the product run - but ignore if the cumulative didn't change (i.e. no more products where actually packed)
- As in the example table, the same product can have multiple runs a day but the summary should show each individual product run.

Create table and insert data....

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Product] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [datetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Cumulative_Packed] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'1         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:15:00.000' AS DateTime), 10)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'2         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:16:00.000' AS DateTime), 22)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'3         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:17:00.000' AS DateTime), 35)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'4         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:18:00.000' AS DateTime), 40)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'5         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:19:00.000' AS DateTime), 40)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'6         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:20:00.000' AS DateTime), 40)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'7         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:21:00.000' AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'8         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:22:00.000' AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'9         ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:23:00.000' AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'10        ', N'Item2', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 12)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'11        ', N'Item2', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:25:00.000' AS DateTime), 18)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'12        ', N'Item2', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:26:00.000' AS DateTime), 18)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'13        ', N'Item2', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:27:00.000' AS DateTime), 22)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'14        ', N'Item2', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:28:00.000' AS DateTime), 22)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'15        ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:29:00.000' AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'16        ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 7)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'17        ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:31:00.000' AS DateTime), 30)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'18        ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:32:00.000' AS DateTime), 38)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'19        ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:33:00.000' AS DateTime), 38)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'20        ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:34:00.000' AS DateTime), 38)
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Product], [datetime], [Cumulative_Packed]) VALUES (N'21        ', N'Item1', CAST(N'2019-11-14T14:35:00.000' AS DateTime), 38)
```

Comment: Not sure how you define your endtime.

Comment: Also give the create table and insert data statements.

Comment: Post updated with create table and insert code. Thanks

Comment: Endtime is defined on last record before next Item. But onyl where cumulative increased. So in the example I give. For product run 1 I expected end time as 14:18 because cumulative packed did not increase 14:19 and 14:20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `lead()` and `lag()` to identify the starts and stops.  For your data:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(datetime)) as run_order,
       product, min(datetime), max(datetime),
       max(cumulative_packed)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_cp = 0 or prev_cp is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by product order by datetime) as rungrp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(cumulative_packed) over (partition by product order by datetime) as prev_cp,
                   lead(cumulative_packed) over (partition by product order by datetime) as next_cp
             from t
            ) t
       where (prev_cp = 0 or prev_cp is null) or              -- is start
             (next_cp = cp or next_cp = 0 or next_cp is null) -- is stop
      ) t
group by rungrp, product
order by rungrp, product, min(datetime);
```

EDIT:

Your data seems to require duplicate removal.  From what I follow, you just need the *first* time the value changes.  This can be handled with one additional layer of subqueries:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(datetime)) as run_order,
       product, min(datetime), max(datetime),
       max(cumulative_packed)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_cp = 0 or prev_cp is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by product order by datetime) as rungrp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(cumulative_packed) over (partition by product order by datetime) as prev_cp,
                   lead(cumulative_packed) over (partition by product order by datetime) as next_cp
             from (select t.*,
                          lag(cumulative_packed) over (partition by product order by datetime) as first_prev_cp
                   from t
                  ) t
             where first_prev_cp is null or first_prev_cp <> cumulative_packed
            ) t
       where (prev_cp = 0 or prev_cp is null) or              -- is start
             (next_cp = cp or next_cp = 0 or next_cp is null) -- is stop
      ) t
group by rungrp, product
order by rungrp, product, min(datetime);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - but isn't quite there.  The finish time is actually when the last pack was registered. In the example I give, for the first product run of item 1 i was expecting the finish time to be 14:18 as nothing was actually packed 14:19 or 14:20.

Comment: @danielcharlesworth . . . I edited the answer.  I think you only need the first time that a particular "cumulative" packed appears in a sequence.  This should work better for your purposes.

Comment: I think your on the right lines but your query fails to run - I've had a go with the code but I end up with the lowest cumulative packed and start/end times are incorrect.

Comment: @danielcharlesworth . . . Wrong comparison.  Try it now.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - works in principal on my test data - i'll apply to actual. Many Thanks

Comment: I've tested this with actual data and found a problem. If the first row in the transactions table start with cumulative = 0 it gives me an extra row showing this transaction only.

Comment: @danielcharlesworth . . . In the outer query, you can actually filter out all the rows with `cumulative = 0`.  Those rows are needed in the subqueries to define the groups, but are not needed for the outer aggregation.